# how to list all questions that has no answer in online discussion forum

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating online discussion forum in PHP as my last semester project and I want to list all questions that have no answers in unanswered page, same as in Stack Overflow.

But I have no idea that how to implement that; I search a lot in internet but still I can't find that how to list all questions that has no answers.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
@session_start();
include("include/user_header.php");
include("include/connection.php");


$query="SELECT * FROM question WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM answer WHERE answer.question_id = question.question_id);"
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                            if(action=="pass_id")
                                            {
                                                document.frm_cms.action="answer.php";
                                                <!--document.frm_que.myaction.value=action;-->
                                                document.frm_cms.id.value=id;   
                                                document.frm_cms.submit();
                                            }


                                        </script>
<div class="main-container">
     <div class="another-main-container row">        

    <div class="ask-question-container">

        <div class="ask-question-container-inner row">
            <form name="frm_cms" method="post" class="printable">
                    <div class="question-usr-prfl row">
                    <h1 class="usr-hdng"><span class="qustn-fgr-usr-prfl"></span> Questions</h1>
                    <ul class="row list-of-questions">
                        <?php
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {   
                        ?>
                                    <li class="row">
                                    <a href="javascript:setAction('pass_id','<?php echo $row['question_id']; ?>');" >
                                        <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="quest-tag-cntr row">
                                    <?php 
                                        $tgNm = explode(",",$row['tag_name']);
                                        for($k=0;$k<count($tgNm);$k++)
                                        {
                                            $k+1;
                                    ?>
                                            <a href='question.php?id=<?php echo $tgNm[$k]; ?>'>
                                    <?php
                                                echo getFromId("tag", "tag_name", "id", $tgNm[$k]);
                                    ?>
                                            </a>
                                    <?php
                                        }                                                       
                                    ?>
                                    </div><!--/quest-tag-cntr-->  
                                </li>
                        <?php
                            }                                                       
                        ?>                                                                                 
                    </ul>


           </div><!--/question-usr-prfl-->
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
include("include/user_footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan he means like SO, not from SO

Comment: this is not a place where you can complete your assignment. You can get help but you have to show us some tried effort first.

Comment: i have not implement code.. @gbestard

Comment: @RajeevRanjan He doesn't want to get all unaswered questions from Stack Overflow on their website but he has a website like Stack Overflow and want to list his own unanswered questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is worth a try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT question.id
FROM question
LEFT JOIN answer ON (question.id = answer.question_id)
WHERE answer.id IS NULL
```

I've left-joined to the answer table (since we want that join to fail) and then compared a non-null column to `NULL`. Rows that return are therefore questions that do not have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try anything ? With an SQL database, it's simple.

```
SELECT *
FROM question
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM answer
    WHERE answer.question_id = question.question_id
);
```